# Negate $\forall x\ \exists y\ \Big(y>0 \to (-2 < x \leq 6)\Big)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I believe the answer to be

> $$\exists x\ \forall y\ \Big(y>0 \to \lnot(-2 < x \leq 6)\Big)$$

If not what help/resources can you give me?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $$\exists x\forall y\Big(y>0\ \textbf{AND}\ \big(-2<x\leq 6\big)\Big).$$

Comment: Ohhh wow that was quick thanks!

Comment: One question I understand now why you used the AND, but if the negation of if p then q is p and not q, would I still not use the negation symbol before the (-2<x<=6)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. $\neg(p\implies q)$ is $p$ AND $\neg q$.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I dont mean to bother you, I understand p and not q, but wouldn't that mean you need to negate the equation after the AND? or is that accomplished by ∃x∀y? I am new to these types of equations and they are really throwing me through a loop

Comment: Yes of course, but in you original "equation", there is already a negation. Since $\neg(\neg p)=p$, the claim follow. Is it clear ?

Comment: Yes thank you! I appreciate your help

Comment: There should be a negation after the "and". The original statement was $y > 0 \rightarrow (-2 < x \leq 6)$, so negated this would be $y > 0 \wedge \lnot (-2 < x \leq 6)$.

Comment: @AtharAbdul-Quader: No it's not ! See the post. But indeed, there is an error in the title.

Comment: The post just states @whatamii 's solution attempt. Which is why there is a negation in that post. The title states the original statement to be negated.